# Export iCal events to .ics file on osx

Tags: macos, cocoa, icalendar, calendar-store

i need to create application which export all iCal events to isc file.Can you advice me how i can to do? With Cocoa Application, Command Line Tool or AppleScript Application?....I am trying to do this with AppleScript Application, using CalendarStore Framework.I'm able to get all events, but how to save thems to ics file??

Here is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)btnSelector:(id)sender {
CalCalendarStore *calendarStore = [CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore];
NSDate *startDate=[[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
startDate=[formatter dateFromString:@"2010-01-01 00:00:00"];                             
NSDate *endDate=[[NSDate alloc] init];    
 endDate=[formatter dateFromString:@"2050-01-01 00:00:00"];

 NSArray *calendars = [calendarStore calendars];
    NSPredicate *allEventsPredicate = [CalCalendarStore eventPredicateWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:[calendarStore calendars]];

NSArray *events = [calendarStore eventsWithPredicate:allEventsPredicate]; 

for(CalEvent *event in events)
{
    //here i must save event to file...
    NSLog(@"%@",event);
    }

for (CalCalendar *calendar in calendars) {

    self.lblNotification.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",self.lblNotification.title,calendar.title];

}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem...now i don't use CalendareStore framework, i just read content of calendars folder:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
//   /Users/username/Library/Calendars
NSError *err;

NSArray *usersFolder = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users" error:&err];

for (NSString *dirElement in usersFolder) {
   // NSLog(@"users folder : %@",dirElement);

    NSString *userCalendarPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Library/Calendars",dirElement];
    NSArray *contentCalendarDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:userCalendarPath error:nil];
    NSArray *calendarFolders = [contentCalendarDirectory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.calendar'"]];

    NSMutableArray *calendarNames= [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];

    for(NSString *calendarFolder in calendarFolders)
    {
       // NSLog(@"calendar folder %@/%@",userCalendarPath,calendarFolder);

        NSString * fullCalendarInfoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Info.plist",userCalendarPath,calendarFolder];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: fullCalendarInfoPath];


        NSString * eventsDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Events",userCalendarPath,calendarFolder];
        NSArray *contentEventsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:eventsDirectory error:nil];
        NSArray *events = [contentEventsDirectory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.ics'"]];


        for(NSString* eventName in events)
        {
            NSString * eventPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Events/%@",userCalendarPath,calendarFolder,eventName];
             //this array contain all ics paths...
//to read file content:
//NSString *eventContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:eventPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            [eventsPath addObject:eventPath];

          }
         NSString* calendarTitle = [dict objectForKey: @"Title"];

        [calendarNames addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  (%lu events)",calendarTitle,[events count]]];

    }
    if(calendarNames.count>0)
    { 
       NSDictionary *userCalendars = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dirElement,@"parent",calendarNames,@"children", nil];
       [dataCalendars addObject:userCalendars];
       }    
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

I went with a different approach — I used GUI scripting to export a specified number of calendars from the Apple Calendar app. It either exports to the Desktop or the Documents folder, I can probably edit the script to force it to export to the Desktop folder.

https://github.com/chinwayland/applescripts/blob/master/wintec-scripts/Export%20Calendars%20to%20ICS.applescript

```
-- This script exports multiple calendars to ICS one by one using GUI Scripting

use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

set numberOfCalendars to display dialog "How many calendars?" default answer ""

tell application "Calendar"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Calendar"
        repeat with i from 2 to text returned of numberOfCalendars as number
            
            # Select each calendar
            tell row i of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
                set selected to true
                delay 1
            end tell
            
            # Click Export from Menu
            tell menu item 1 of menu of menu item "Export" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
                click
                delay 3
            end tell
            
            # Click Export Button from pop up window
            tell button "Export" of sheet 1 of window 1
                click
                delay 1
            end tell
            
            
            if button "Replace" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 exists then
                tell button "Replace" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
                    click
                end tell
                delay 1
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```